# Collecting actions and branching out early if necessary

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm converting some Python code to Haskell. The business logic is fairly complex and my Haskell code is getting ugly.

My Python function:

```
def f(some_state):
    doAction1() # e.g. send_message("Hi there!")
    if not userIsAuthenticated:
        doAction2() # e.g. send_message("Please login")
        return
    if not userHasPermission:
        doAction3() # e.g. send_message("Please sudo")
        return
    if somePredicate3:
        doAction4()
        if somePredicate4:
            doAction5()
    return
```

I have two constraints for the Haskell version:

1. In order to keep my code as pure possible, I'd like to collect all my actions in a list (or a Free Monad if I'm feeling fancy) and then (outside the function) execute it. In Python, I would defined `tmp = []` at the beginning of my function, append to `tmp` all my actions (without calling them) and return `tmp`. Then, I'd iterate over the list to execute all the actions (not Pythonic at all!).
2. **Not** end up with pushed-to-the-right craziness like this:

-

```
if a
then undefined
else if b
     then undefined
     else if c
          then undefined
          else if d
               then undefined
               else undefined
```

Basically, I want to collect a list of actions and exit early if necessary, so that I can write something like:

```
tell Action1
when somePredicate1 $ tell doAction2
when somePredicate2 $ tell doAction3
...
```

`tell` is NOT from the writer monad but it's a function (which doesn't exist) that aggregates everything that has been "told" so far (à la writer monad) and is returned when I exit.

This really feels like a generalized Either monad, except that I need to keep all the actions that happened before the first Left (and not just the Left value) and then exit early at the first Left. I think the solution probably builds on MonadPlus or Alternative somehow, but I just can't figure out something nice. Basically, a fancy `guard`.

It's also definitely possible that I'm having too much fun over-engineering this and I should just accept that my code has to drift right. But that wouldn't be elegant, would it?

Edit: For clarity, I want a function of type `f :: State -> [Action]`, where `data Action = Action1 | Action2 | Action3`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an ideal use of `throwError`, from mtl's [Control.Monad.Except](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html), like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards  #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.Except

data UnlockError =
    UnlockErrorNoLogin
  | UnlockErrorNeedsSudo

data State = State {
    stateUserIsAuthenticated :: Bool
  , stateUserHasPermission :: Bool
  }

unlock :: MonadError UnlockError m => State -> m String
unlock State{..} = do
  action1
  unless stateUserIsAuthenticated
         (throwError UnlockErrorNoLogin)
  unless stateUserHasPermission
         (throwError UnlockErrorNeedsSudo)
  return "all"
  where
    action1 = return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
  state <- conjureState
  case unlock state of
    Left UnlockErrorNoLogin ->
      p "please log in"
    Left UnlockErrorNeedsSudo ->
      p "please sudo"
    Right count ->
      p ("i love you with " ++ show count ++ " of my heart")
  where
    p =
      putStrLn
    conjureState =
      return (State True True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution :) Although I'd like `unlock` to return `[action1, UnlockErrorNoLogin]` or `[action1, UnlockErrorNeedsSudo]`. Ie, given `data Actions = Action1 | ActionIfNoLogin | ActionIfNeedsSudo` I want to collect a list of actions that depends on the execution of the function. But `Action1` is not monadic.

Comment: @cpa If the monadic action has indeed executed far enough to reach one of the errors above, it will indeed have executed the `action1` action.

Comment: My OP wasn't very clear (I updated it), but I don't want to execute the action, but return a list of actions to execute. After a good night sleep, I think I'm just reinventing free monads, actually.

Comment: @cpa What are you going to do with it if not execute?

Comment: I want to batch all the actions then execute them in another function. Anyway, I think Free monads solve my problem.

Comment: @cpa So... you *are* going to execute them. So why go all the way to free monads? Why not just execute them?

Comment: Because I want to keep my business logic pure.